# Oracle months_between function unexpected result

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle's months_between function returns unexpected results.

For example, the difference between 20191001 and 20190916 is 15 days, so the return value of the function is expected to be (1/31) * 15 = 0.4838 ....

```
SELECT months_between('20191001','20190916')
from dual
```

.5161290322580645161290322580645161290323

Is this a specification? Or is it a bug?

Comment: Seems to return 16/31, i.e both start and end dates included.

Comment: probably not included SELECT months_between(date '2019-09-30', date '2019-09-15') 
from dual   returns 0.4838

Comment: Specification; see the manual section "purpose":https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function MONTHS_BETWEEN works with 31 day months when the day-of-the-month is not the last day of the month.

```
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN 
  (TO_DATE('20190201','YYYYMMDD'),
   TO_DATE('20190131','YYYYMMDD') ) "Months"
FROM DUAL;
```

will return 0.032 (rounded) but

```
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN 
 (TO_DATE('20190301','YYYYMMDD'),
  TO_DATE('20190228','YYYYMMDD') ) "Months"
FROM DUAL;
```

will return 0.129

For a more complete description of MONTHS_BETWEN see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm)

Comment: Not quite universally true but works for this scenario. Docs say *"Purpose

MONTHS_BETWEEN returns number of months between dates date1 and date2. If date1 is later than date2, then the result is positive. If date1 is earlier than date2, then the result is negative. **If date1 and date2 are either the same days of the month or both last days of months, then the result is always an integer.** Otherwise Oracle Database calculates the fractional portion of the result based on a 31-day month and considers the difference in time components date1 and date2."*

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for pointing this out. I read the above documentation but got so focused on addressing the particular issue in the question that I forgot to mentioning the other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version for SQL Server which is accurate.

```
/***************************************************************************
    Name    : fsMonthsBetweenDates
    Purpose : Mimics the Months_Between function in Oracle; except this one is 100% accurate
    Author  : Gordon de Rouyan
    Date    : 2022-09-24
***************************************************************************/
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fsMonthsBetweenDates
(
    @Date1 datetime, 
    @Date2 datetime,
    @InclusiveFirstDay bit = 1
) 
RETURNS numeric(10,5)
WITH SCHEMABINDING -- , INLINE = ON  -- compatibility_level = 150
AS
BEGIN
    -- Using all floats for numeric values
    DECLARE @Months numeric(10,5) = 0;

    IF @Date1 IS NOT NULL AND @Date2 IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        -- Include the first day or not; e.g. 2021-02-01 and 2021-02-01
        -- Do you want to consider this combination as one day 2021-02-01@00:00:00 to 2021-02-01@23:59:59?
        DECLARE @FirstDayInclusive int =    CASE
                                                WHEN @InclusiveFirstDayFlag = 1 THEN 1
                                                ELSE 0
                                            END;

        -- Determine start date
        DECLARE @StartDt date = CASE
                                    WHEN CAST(@Date2 AS date) > CAST(@Date1 AS date) THEN @Date1
                                    ELSE @Date2
                                END;

        -- Determine end date
        DECLARE @EndDt date =   CASE
                                    WHEN CAST(@Date2 AS date) > CAST(@Date1 AS date) THEN @Date2
                                    ELSE @Date1
                                END;
        
        DECLARE -- The DAY portion of the dates
                @StartDtDay int = DAY(@StartDt),
                @EndDtDay int = DAY(@EndDt),

                -- Number of days in each month specific to each supplied date; exact with leap year
                @StartDtMonthDays numeric(7,5) = DAY(EOMONTH(@StartDt)),
                @EndDtMonthDays numeric(7,5) = DAY(EOMONTH(@EndDt));

        
        DECLARE -- The fraction of the first month
                @FirstMonthFraction numeric(6,5) =  (@StartDtMonthDays - @StartDtDay + @FirstDayInclusive) / @StartDtMonthDays,

                -- The fraction of the last month
                @LastMonthFraction numeric(6,5) = @EndDtDay / @EndDtMonthDays;

        SET @Months = DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDt, @EndDt) - 1 + (@FirstMonthFraction + @LastMonthFraction);
    END;
 
    RETURN @Months; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version for SQL Server which mimics the same output as Oracle.

```
/***************************************************************************
    Name    : fsOracleMonths_Between
    Purpose : Mimics the Months_Between function in Oracle; exactly the same values
    Author  : Gordon de Rouyan
    Date    : 2022-09-24
***************************************************************************/
CREATE OR ALTER   FUNCTION [dbo].[fsOracleMonths_Between]
(
    @Date1 datetime, 
    @Date2 datetime
) 
RETURNS numeric(10,5)
WITH SCHEMABINDING  -- , INLINE = ON  -- SQL Server 2019, compatibility_level = 150
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Months numeric(10,5) = 0,
            @OmbDate1 date = @Date1,
            @OmbDate2 date = @Date2;

    IF      @Date1 IS NOT NULL AND @Date2 IS NOT NULL
        AND @OmbDate1 <> @OmbDate2
    BEGIN
        -- Compare the datetime values
        DECLARE @Date2GreaterThanDate1Flag bit  =   CASE
                                                        WHEN @OmbDate1 <= @OmbDate2 THEN 1
                                                        ELSE 0
                                                    END;

        -- This ensures the correct value comes out based on the numeric(7,5)
        -- int / numeric(7,5) = numeric(7,5)
        -- numeric(7,5) / 31 = error
        DECLARE @ConstantDay numeric(7,5) = 31;
        
        -- The DAY portion of the dates
        DECLARE @Date1Day int = DAY(@OmbDate1),
                @Date2Day int = DAY(@OmbDate2);

        -- Number of days in each month specific to each supplied date; exact with leap year
        DECLARE @Date1MonthDays int = DAY(EOMONTH(@OmbDate1)),
                @Date2MonthDays int = DAY(EOMONTH(@OmbDate2));

        -- The fraction of the start month
        DECLARE @StartMonthFraction numeric(6,5) =  CASE
                                                        WHEN @Date2GreaterThanDate1Flag = 1 THEN (@ConstantDay - @Date1Day) / @ConstantDay
                                                        ELSE (@ConstantDay - @Date2Day) / @ConstantDay
                                                    END;

        -- The fraction of the end month
        DECLARE @EndMonthFraction numeric(6,5) =    CASE
                                                        WHEN @Date2GreaterThanDate1Flag = 1 THEN @Date2Day / @ConstantDay
                                                        ELSE @Date1Day / @ConstantDay
                                                    END;

        SET @Months =   CASE
                            WHEN @Date2GreaterThanDate1Flag = 1 THEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, @OmbDate2, @OmbDate1 ) + 1 - (@StartMonthFraction + @EndMonthFraction)
                            ELSE DATEDIFF(MONTH, @OmbDate2, @OmbDate1) - 1 + (@StartMonthFraction + @EndMonthFraction)
                        END;
    END;
 
    RETURN @Months;
END;
```